# If $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = L > 0$. Prove. $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt{a_n} = \sqrt{L}$ converges

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

If $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = L > 0$. Prove. $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt{a_n} = \sqrt{L}$ converges.

Proof Attempt: $$\Bigg|\sqrt{a_n} - \sqrt{L}\Bigg|= \Bigg|\frac{a_n - L}{\sqrt{a_n} + \sqrt{L}}\Bigg|$$

Note:

$\Bigg|\sqrt{a_n} - \sqrt{L}\Bigg| \leq \Bigg|\sqrt{a_n} + \sqrt{L}\Bigg| \leq \Bigg| a_{n} + L \Bigg| $

If I take the limit of the last inequality this would mean: $$ \Bigg| a_{n} + L \Bigg| \leq 2L$$

Therefore take $\epsilon = 2L$  and this would satisfy the expression.

I feel it should've been a little simpler than this. Where did I go wrong?

**EDIT/ Possible Solution Redone**:

By the Archimedian Property of real numbers there is  a big enough value of $n$ such that $a_n > \frac{L}{4}$ (Other fractions could also be used assuming truth of property).

$\therefore \  $$a_n > \frac{L}{4} \Rightarrow \sqrt{a_n} > \frac{\sqrt{L}}{2}$$

Then:  $\Bigg|\sqrt{a_n}+\sqrt{L}\Bigg| > \Bigg| \frac{\sqrt{L}}{2} + \sqrt{L} \Bigg|$

Which implies: $|\frac{1}{|\frac{3 \sqrt{L}}{2}|} > \frac{1} {|\sqrt{a_n} + \sqrt{L}|}$

Looking at the expression again and manipulation:

$$\Bigg|\frac{a_n - L}{\sqrt{a_n} + \sqrt{L}}\Bigg| \leq \frac{|a_n - L|}{|\sqrt{a_n} + \sqrt{L}|} <  \frac{2 \Bigg| a_n - L \Bigg|}{3 \sqrt{L}} < \frac{2 \epsilon}{3 \sqrt{L}} < \epsilon$$

Therefore $|\sqrt{a_n} - \sqrt{L}|$ will converge if we take the same $N$ that works for our assumption.

Comment: Where did $|\sqrt{a_n}-\sqrt{L}|\leq|\sqrt{a_n}+\sqrt{L}|\leq|a_n+L|$ come from?

Comment: Where did you bring the inequality $\frac{|a_n-L|}{|\sqrt{a_n}+\sqrt{L}|}<|a_n-L|$ from? The denominator might be smaller than $1$ and then it is not true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot *take* $\varepsilon=2L$. Asserting that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{a_n}=\sqrt L$ means that for *every* $\varepsilon>0$, there is a natural $N$ such that$$n\geqslant N\implies\left\lvert\sqrt{a_n}-\sqrt L\right\rvert<\varepsilon.$$

---

Concerning the edited version: why do you think that$$\frac{|a_n - L|}{\left|\sqrt{a_n} + \sqrt L\right|} < \lvert a_n - L \rvert?$$

---

In order to prove what you wish to prove, you can use the fact that$$(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):\left\lvert\sqrt{a_n}+L\right\rvert=\sqrt{a_n}+L\geqslant L$$and that therefore$$\frac{\lvert a_n-L\rvert}{\left\lvert\sqrt{a_n}+\sqrt L\right\rvert}\leqslant\frac1{\sqrt L}\lvert a_n-L\rvert.$$

Comment: I made a change to the solution. Is my edit the correct thought process?

Comment: @dc3rd I have already made an edition to my answer concerning the edited version of your question.

Comment: you are right. There is the possibility that $|\sqrt{a_n} + \sqrt{L}| < 1$....... Can I bound this by chance?

Comment: Hint: for big values of $n$ you have $a_n>\frac{L}{4}$. Try to think how can it effect the denominator in your expression.

Comment: @Mark where did that hint come from?.....WOuld that mean the sequence is bounded below?

Comment: You can conclude this from the definition of $a_n$ converging to $L$. Yes, it is bounded from below by a positive number. You already got a few answers here that generalize my hint.

Comment: @Mark I added in a bunch of steps to my solution. WOuld what I wrote be the correct way to reason it out?

Comment: Yes, your solution looks good.

Comment: @Mark Thank you, but note that it has to be changed a little if $L=0$.

Comment: @Mark  Thank you for your help.  As well to you Jose Carlos. Is my using the Archimedes principle correct?

Comment: No, you are not. The existence of such a $n$ follows from the definition of convergent sequence. It has nothing to do with the Archimedes principle.

Comment: so Jose, if that is the case then any fraction $\frac{L}{M}$ where M is just a random number could've satisfied the expression $a_n > \frac{L}{M}$  where $L < M$?

Comment: If $M>1$, then, yes, $a_n>\frac LM$ if $n$ is large enough.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \Bigg|\frac{a_n - L}{\sqrt{a_n} + \sqrt{L}}\Bigg| \leq \frac{|a_n - L|}{|\sqrt{a_n} + \sqrt{L}|} \le \frac{| a_n - L |}{\sqrt{L}}$$

Hence, given $\epsilon>0$.

Find $N>0$ such that $n>N$ implies $|a_n-L| < \sqrt{L}\epsilon$